# Specify exact type of functional component as prop in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, types, properties, react-functional-component

I want to achieve a simple (?) task. I want to create my custom functional component that accepts two components as params: a `Text` and a `Button`. I need that exactly those types are passed, so if I'll pass a `View` it should not work.

I tried with:

```
interface SampleArgs {
  text: ReactElement<TextProps>;
  button: ReactElement<ButtonProps>;
}

const Sample = ({ text, button }: SampleArgs) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
      {text}
      {button}
    </View>
  );
};

export { Sample };
```

But when I'm trying to use it inside my `App.tsx` every component is accepted without any complains:

```
{/* No warnings/error, ok! */}
<Sample
  text={<Text>I should work!</Text>}
  button={<Button title={'I should work'}/>}/>

{/* No warnings/error, hey, it shouldn't work! */}
<Sample
  text={
    <View>
      <Text>Passed View instead of Text, I shouldn't work!</Text>
    </View>
  }
  button={<Text>Passed Text instead of Button, I shouldn't work!</Text>}
/>
```

Specifying in the interface `text: Text;` works, but then I cannot use `text={<Text>I should work!</Text>}` anymore because `Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Text'.`

Specifying in the interface `text: ReactElement<Text>;` works, but any element is accepted anyway.

Yes, functional components are required, we don't use class ones anymore.

## Is there a way to achieve this and restrict types of component?

Answer (score 0):

I found an **ugly** workaround. You can use props to create an actual element.

```
interface SampleArgs {
  textProps: TextProps;
...

const element = React.createElement(Text, textProps);
return (
   <View>
       {element}
...
```

In this way you can create a `Text` component, and trying to do `const element = React.createElement(Button, textProps);` will show an error: `Property 'title' is missing in type 'TextProps' but required in type 'ButtonProps'`

The downside of this solution is that in order to create a `Text` component from outside you need specify attributes of a `Text` element, so there is no `text` but `children` property, and your code is less readable.

```
<Sample
    textProps={{ children: 'Hello my darling', style: { backgroundColor: '#ff0022' } }}
...
```